# Getting write permission from HDFS after updating flink-1.40 to flink-1.4.2

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, apache-flink, cloudera-cdh

**Environment**

- Flink-1.4.2
- Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.13.0 with 4 nodes in service and `Security is off.`
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Java 8

**Description**

I have a Java job in flink-1.4.0 which writes to HDFS in a specific path. 
After updating to flink-1.4.2 I'm getting the following error from Hadoop complaining that the user doesn't have write permission to the given path:

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:xng (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=user1, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
```

**NOTE**:

- If I run the same job on flink-1.4.0, Error disappears regardless of what version of flink (1.4.0 or 1.4.2) dependencies I have for job
- Also if I run the job main method from my IDE and pass the same parameters, I don't get above error.

**Question**
Any Idea what's wrong? Or how to fix?

Comment: A small Update (since I can't edit the post): I'm getting this error in flink-1.4.1 as well.

Comment: Update: It seems the problem somehow is in `flink-1.4.2/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.4.2.jar`. If I replace that with `flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.4.0.jar`, restart the cluster and run my job (flink topology) then the error doesn't appear.